# How to avoid overwriting my xml database?

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, ado.net

I am trying to write a WinForms application that takes data from a datagrid and appends it to an xml file, but my code is overwriting existing data.

I add data to the datagrid by reading values from textboxes

```
    private void add_row_BTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int add = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
        dataGridView1.Rows[add].Cells[0].Value = textBox1.Text;
        dataGridView1.Rows[add].Cells[1].Value = textBox2.Text;
        dataGridView1.Rows[add].Cells[2].Value = textBox4.Text;
        dataGridView1.Rows[add].Cells[3].Value = textBox5.Text;
        dataGridView1.Rows[add].Cells[4].Value = textBox6.Text;
        dataGridView1.Rows[add].Cells[5].Value = textBox3.Text;
    }
```

Here is where I save the data from the DataGridView

```
    private void save_BTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.TableName = "Employees";
        dt.Columns.Add("Name");
        dt.Columns.Add("E-Mail");
        dt.Columns.Add("Age");
        dt.Columns.Add("WorkHours");
        dt.Columns.Add("Gender");
        dt.Columns.Add("JobTitle");
        ds.Tables.Add (dt);
        DataRow dr = ds.Tables["Employees"].NewRow();
        dr["Name"] = textBox1.Text;
        dr["E-Mail"] = textBox2.Text;
        dr["Age"] = textBox4.Text;
        dr["WorkHours"] = textBox5.Text;
        dr["Gender"] = textBox6.Text;
        dr["JobTitle"] = textBox3.Text;
        ds.Tables["Employees"].Rows.Add(dr);

        ds.WriteXml("Data.xml");

    }
```

Comment: What do you *want* it to do?  What should happen to your previous data, and what should happen to your new data?  They can't share the same file name, obviously.

Comment: I want the program to take data from text boxes  and save it to  the XML file without overwriting the old data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Overload method to  give input as below

```
System.IO.FileStream stream = new System.IO.FileStream(@"Data.xml", System.IO.FileMode.Append);

            // Write to the file with the WriteXml method.
            ds.WriteXml(stream);
```

Comment: I tried it  and it works but,
I  have to close and open the program to  input  new  data

Comment: call stream.close() after use to close the stream .